# How to I extend my buttons from end to end on the page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to extend the buttons to be full page width, regardless of the device. Being in Wordpress, it's contained. So I want to extend the button across from one end to the other. I thought about adding in margins and upping the width, but then I can't account for the specific device, especially with the text being centered.

Should I be approaching this differently like changing it to a div table? Or just need to modify the button properties?

CSS

```
@media screen and 
    (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  div.title {
    font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 35pt;
  }
    div.subtitle {
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 25pt;
    }
    div.description {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20pt;
    }
    button.btn-primary {
        font-size: 25px;
        display: block;
    }
    button.btn-secondary {
        font-size: 25px;
        display: block;
    }
}

.title {
  text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
  font-size: 80pt;
    line-height: 91pt;
    font-family: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", sans-serif;
}

.subtitle {
  text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
  font-size: 36pt;
    font-family: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", sans-serif;
  margin: 4px 2px;
    letter-spacing: -0.020em;
}

.description {
  text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-family: "Avenir Next Condensed" !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 30pt;
    letter-spacing: -0.020em;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #700D0D;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
    float: left;
    justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.020em;
  cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-secondary {
  background-color: #C32D0A;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
    float: left;
    justify-content: center;
  font-size: 48px;
    font-family: "Futura-CondensedExtraBold", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -0.020em;
  cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}

.btn-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">LEARN ABOUT EVERYTHING</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block">ONE FOR THE ROAD</button>
```

Comment: Just a side note, If you want a `media query` for `mobile devices`, you should use `@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {}`. Almost every smartphone is between that resolution, in `portrait` mode.

Comment: Thanks! I changed that up for now. Still trying out other code but nothing as of yet where font size changes

Comment: You have `flex` properties on the buttons, yet you don't have a `flex` parent in your example.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. I just pulled this as I was testing various combinations.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Better to clean the long CSS and leave only the relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the following  viewport element in all your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A  viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The width=device-width part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The initial-scale=1.0 part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.